# CMake cannot find Boost libraries filestem, thread, date_time, iostreams, system

Tags: c++, boost, build, cmake

I am attempting to build PCL from source, but CMake cannot locate some of the libraries. However when I check the libraries are there. I know this has been asked plenty already but I am just starting out with CMake I've been searching the internet for days and can't find a solution that works. I feel like I'm missing something any help would be appreciated

So I wrote this in my CMakeLists.txt as others have suggested

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.67.0")
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/local/boost_1_67_0/boost")

set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "C:/local/boost_1_67_0/")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "C:/local/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.0")

set (Boost_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.67.0)
```

but I still keep getting the same error:

```
     CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2100 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.67.0

  Boost include path: C:/local/boost_1_67_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_filesystem
          boost_thread
          boost_date_time
          boost_iostreams
          boost_system

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/pcl_find_boost.cmake:36 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:428 (include)
```

Honestly I'll take any suggestions of things I can try at this point. And feel free to comment or message if I can provide any other useful information that I am not thinking of.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like timko.mate suggested, `find_package` with components is the right way to do.

However, you should consider using the target based API:

```
target_link_libraries(your_exe PUBLIC Boost::system Boost::filesystem)
```

Also, to make CMake finds Boost, you should adjust your prefix path. This is usually done when invoking cmake in your project:

```
cmake -DMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=c:/local/ ..
```

That way, no hardcoded path should be in your cmake files.

Comment: silly question but what would what .exe would "your_exe" be in this case? I guess I don't fully understand what you mean by using the target APIs instead. Like you suggested include_directories is giving issues.Thanks again for the quick response

Comment: @p0ps1c1e When you call `add_executable(a_exe ...)` or `add_library(a_lib ...)` then `a_lib` and `a_exe` both are *targets*. You can then link the targets to boost's targets to gain include directories. Calling `include_directory(...)` is considered bad practice. You should use `target_link_libraries(...)` and `target_include_directories(...)`

Comment: @p0ps1c1e my bad, I was using the wrong command in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue couple of months before. This solved my problem.

```
find_package(Boost 1.67.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: When using find_package I'd highly recommend using targets based API instead of directories